# Julia LoopVectorization ArgumentError: invalid index: VectorizationBase.MM{2, 1, Int64}<2, 3> of type VectorizationBase.MM{2, 1, Int64}

Tags: julia

I'm trying to solve a 2D PDE over a large finite difference grid. I have a written my own small function to perform a Laplacian operation over this grid. Currently the model is fairly slow, and I am trying to speed up the matrix operations. I have added the `@turbo` macro from LoopVectorization.jl to see what difference this makes. The Laplacian code is now as follows:

```
module Laplacian

using LinearAlgebra
using LoopVectorization

@inline @views function ∇²!(∇²u, u, N, h, a)

    @turbo for j = 2+a:N+5-a
        for i = 2+a:N+5-a
            ∇²u[i,j] = (u[i-1,j] + u[i+1,j] + u[i,j-1] + u[i,j+1] - 4*u[i,j])/h^2
        end
    end

    return nothing

end

export ∇²!

end
```

`∇²u` is the preallocated array in which to store the result eg `∇²u = zeros(N+6,N+6)`

`u` is the field to which the Laplacian is applied eg `u = rand(N+6,N+6)`

`N` is the number of grid points in u (minus the 6 ghost points in each dimension eg `N=400`

`h` is the distance between grid points eg `h=0.1`

`a` is the number of ghost points to skip at the edges of the matrix eg `a=1`

Unfortunately this produces the following error:
`ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid index: VectorizationBase.MM{2, 1, Int64}<4, 5> of type VectorizationBase.MM{2, 1, Int64}`

I cannot figure out what what this error means or what the problem here is. Can anyone advise?

Comment: I have added some explanation and examples of the arguments. I hope that helps.

Comment: I think the problem is the `@views` macro. If you run `@macroexpand1` on this, you will see that what `@turbo` is receiving looks quite unlike what it usually expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @mcabbot's comment, I can confirm that the problem is coming from the `@views` macro. Fortunately, that macro is actually also entirely unnecessary in this case, since you are not taking any slices of an array that would allocate anyways at any point within this function. So, for instance the following works without error on my system:

```
using LinearAlgebra
using LoopVectorization

@inline function ∇²!(∇²u, u, N, h, a)

    @turbo for j = 2+a:N+5-a
        for i = 2+a:N+5-a
            ∇²u[i,j] = (u[i-1,j] + u[i+1,j] + u[i,j-1] + u[i,j+1] - 4*u[i,j])/h^2
        end
    end

    return ∇²u # There is no performance cost to returning the result, so might as well!

end

N=400
∇²u = zeros(N+6,N+6)
u = rand(N+6,N+6)
h=0.1
a=1

∇²!(∇²u, u, N, h, a)
```

This should also work fine if you need to pass a `view` *to* this function as an argument -- just don't put the `@views` macro in the function definition:

```
julia> some_big_array = zeros(1000,1000);

julia> ∇²u = view(some_big_array, 1:N+6, 1:N+6); # or equivalently ∇²u = @views some_big_array[1:N+6, 1:N+6]

julia> ∇²!(∇²u, u, N, h, a)
406×406 view(::Matrix{Float64}, 1:406, 1:406) with eltype Float64:
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I have a bad habit of using the @views macro on functions and assuming it won't hurt.